# Moq Index property Callback with SetupGet

Tags: c#, indexing, properties, mocking, moq

I am trying to write a test for an extension method that adds a prefix for a key that gets sent to the index property of IConfiguration:

extension:

```
public static class IConfigurationExt
{
    public static string GetDomainValue(this IConfiguration configuration, string key)
    {
        return configuration["domain." + key];
    }
}
```

test:

```
[Test]
public void GetInexKeyAsCallback()
{
    string keySet = null;

    Mock<IConfiguration> configurationMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    configurationMock.SetupGet(p => p[It.IsAny<string>()])
                        .Callback(() => keySet = "assign key here") // <<< the part here needs the parameter
                        .Returns("mock");

    IConfiguration configuration = configurationMock.Object;

    var result = configuration.GetDomainValue("testKey");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected: "domain.testKey", actual: keySet);
}
```

I am trying to see that when a getter is executed and a key is sent, it will come with the prefix to the index property of IConfiguration.
My problem is that I cannot make the Callback part working with a parameter , such as:
`.Callback<string>((key) => keySet = key)`, for example.

Is there a way of getting the key that was sent to the indexed property?
It works with `SetupSet`, but not with `SetupGet`

Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering why not use `Verify` instead of `Callback`?

Comment: @Johnny that is a very good observation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SetupGet` does not have a `Callback` that allows access to the passed parameter.

Use `Setup` instead and then the `Callback` can access the passed argument by including a parameter in the delegate

```
public void GetInexKeyAsCallback() {
    //Arrange
    string actual = null;
    string expected = "domain.testKey";

    Mock<IConfiguration> configurationMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    configurationMock
        .Setup(_ => _[It.IsAny<string>()]) // <-- Use Setup
        .Callback((string arg) => actual = arg) // <<< the part here gets the parameter
        .Returns("mock");

    IConfiguration configuration = configurationMock.Object;

    //Act
    var result = configuration.GetDomainValue("testKey");

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you already have an answer I would like to suggest the other approach which IMO fits beter in the problem you have described.

> I am trying to see that when a getter is executed and a key is sent,
>   it will come with the prefix to the index property of IConfiguration.

The `Verify` is ment to be used for such a scenario instead of `Callback`. You could rewrite your test to something like this:

```
// Arrange
const string expectedKey = "testKey";
Mock<IConfiguration> configurationMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>(MockBehavior.Strict);
configurationMock.SetupGet(p => p[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns("mock");

// Act
_ = configurationMock.Object.GetDomainValue(expectedKey);

// Assert
configurationMock.Verify(m => m[$"domain.{expectedKey}"], Times.Once);
```

Comment: thanks! I will take a look at ````Verify```` functionality. This one will verify that the property _was_ called 1 time with this key, rather than reacting _when_ the call occurs.

Comment: would it be more accurate to use ````.VerifyGet()```` instead of ````.Verify()```` since I am dealing with the properties?

Comment: Mater of taste. Personally I always use Verify but yes you could use VerifyGet for sure...

Answer (score -1):

From memory you need to change

```
Callback(() =>
```

to

```
Callback<string>( x =>
```

Comment: ````Callback<string>```` with the parameter works with SetupSet, but not with SetupGet